# How would this question be received if I asked it?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I wonder about early processor such as 4-bit microprocessor. Specifically I would like to know about the instruction set and see example program. I found one [link](https://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/DataSheet/4004_datasheet.pdf) about it but I didn't find any example programs. I would like to know the features of the Intel 4004 and see an instruction list. I have found a link to an emulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's only one way to find out!

I expect that it would be well received.  We already have questions on instruction sets of old processors so it wouldn't be out of place.